# Phonegap plugin not working in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am creating phonegap application and using below plugin for sharing and copying link.

Email Composer: https://github.com/hazemhagrass/EmailComposer.git

Copy to clipboard: https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard

Social Media Sharing: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

All this plugins are working perfectly when I create an iOS application. But when I am using eclipse to build android application, copy to clipboard and social sharing plugins are not working.

Please, also let me know if there are any other plugins that are supported both in android and iOS.

This is what I get in log

[image]

This is my config.xml file

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You got any errors? also did the project create by CLI?

Comment: can u give any error messages or logcat snippet? have u configured your config.xml?

Comment: I had added the log status

Comment: this error mostly is caused by unidentified plugin which u havent declared. have u append these plugins to your config.xml?

Comment: yes, plugins are added in config file. Also I had create android project through command line only.

Comment: When you added plugins with CLI , did you get successfully installed..

Comment: usually when i get this kind of error in logcat, i am still able to run my app, so i usually ignore it. is there other error messages or anything? can u provide your config.xml also?

Comment: Ved : Yes, the application was successfully installed

Comment: Fan : I had added the config.xml

Answer (score 0):

you misconfigured your config.xml
you have to assign the value according to the plugin package name

For example the Social Sharing, try to change it to

```
<feature name="SocialSharing">
    <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
</feature>
```

Comment: hmm i'm not sure about the copy to clipboard, but the social sharing i have done successfully before without any trouble. must be something missing. the error in logcat stay exactly the same when you change the param value?

Comment: is this the config.xml from PROJECT/res/xml/config.xml or PROJECT/config.xml?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use another procedure:

Add your "cordova.js" file into www folder and then run the .html file using following line of code in your activity.

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```